# silverlight xaml can't get nullable double

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my app resources i have:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <System:Double x:Key="DefaultMargin">15.0</System:Double>
    ...
```

now in code behind i try to get the value

```
double? margin = Resources["DefaultMargin"] as double?;
```

but it's always null,

My question is:
How can I set a const double in my app so that I can get it from xaml and C#

EDIT: tip: I'm working on WP7/8

Comment: If you know that it is a double, why don't you use it as a double? Why try to cast it to `Nullable<double>`?

Comment: you can't get in c# double from xaml as normal double, only Nullable<double> is allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure about silverlight but in wpf this works. You need to access `App.Current.Resources` since you're storing it there.

```
double? margin = App.Current.Resources["DefaultMargin"] as double?;
```

Comment: thats it! i was missing Current befor Resources, Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Define the value in question on your ViewModel (or whatever your page's context is set to which adheres to INotifyPropertyChanged) and access it that way on both levels.

If you have to access it on the resource then set it like:

```
myWindow.Resources.Add("myResourceKey", myViewModel.myValue);
```

access it in xaml as via a `StaticResource`

```
"{StaticResource myResourceKey}"
```

or as mentioned even binding

```
"{Binding myValue}"
```

Hence there are three ways to get at the value.

Comment: it is an option but you have to set it in c# and I would rather keep all config in xml files